# Want to unwind to view controller but exit button won't highlight, connect in Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode5

Want to connect by control-clicking two bar button items (cancel and done) to the Exit button (to perform an unwind segue) under the Storyboard, but the Exit button won't highlight.

Have checked that I have selected the two bar button items in the document outline view; I have. Why won't the Exit button highlight?

Comment: Which exit segue object are you trying to connect to? The one that belongs to your view controller? Does any previous controller in your hierarchy declare a suitable action?

Comment: Am trying to connect to the green Exit symbol under the Storyboard and which belongs to the VC. No, there are no other segues in my stack; this is the first one.

Comment: If this is the first scene, where would it unwind to? 

Answer (score 1):

Have you implemented an IBAction in your destination view controller ?

This could look like this:

/* Objective-C */

```
- (IBAction)unwindToMainMenu:(UIStoryboardSegue*)sender
{
}
```

/* Swift */

```
@IBAction func unwindToMainMenu(sender: UIStoryboardSegue)
{
}
```

If you have not implemented at least one somewhere, exit button won't highlight.